# access input document in template that matches a node loaded by doc()

Tags: xslt

When applying a template to nodes that are loaded by doc(), how can I access the orignial input document in that template?
Is there another way than adding a parameter like this?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('snippets.xml')//snippet">
    <xsl:with-param name="input-document" select="/" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a global variable e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="primary-input" select="/"/>
```

and then use `$primary-input` where needed. The name of the variable is up to you.